# Detecting contours separated by blank pixel

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently trying to detect contours with opencv of caracters in an image in python and draw a bounding rectangle around this specifics contours.

The problem is that I have a caracter "<" which include noise from scanning it and there is a blank line of 1 pixel in the middle of it. The resulting contours find it's 2 differents contours.

Here is the caracter : [image: problem]

(Before detecting the contours, I'm applying a binary thresholding)

Is there a way to indicate to opencv to concatenate two contours that are too close to each other ?

Cheers,
Astrus

Comment: Apply some morphological operations before finding the contours. A dilate followed by an erode would solve your problem here.

Comment: Just to add to Sunreef's answer, if you are using Canny to find the edges there is a parameter to tune how it joins nearby edges

Comment: @Sunreef it's not that easy because the corresponding image is a representation of 72 aligned caracters. Indeed, I need to find the contours of all the 72 characters and your transformation may hurt the nearby caracters (maybe the others caracters contours are just fine).

Comment: @MartinBeckett I'm not using Canny, I'm currently using opencv findcontours method followed by boundingRect to draw a rectangle around the caracter. Do you think I can use Canny to replace findcontours and use a boundingRect after ?

Comment: @Astrus you generally use something to either find edges (canny) or threshold the image before passing it to findContours. Typically you need to clean up the edge/threshold image by dilation/erosion or other morpholgy stuff before contouring. Ensuring a single character joins up without joining other characters might be tricky - you may have to run findContours after different dilation levels to match all the text

Comment: @Astrus: it is important to understand that no algorithm in the world can guess if two nearby pieces are from a broken character or are two distinct characters. So if your characters are close to each other, what you ask is virtually hopeless. But you should show the whole image.

Answer (score 0):

The code could probably be optimized a lot (barley started with programming) and is very slow but maybe it could help in your case or simply give you an idea. What I did is find all contours and draw them on a blank mask. Then you can determine all non black (zero) pixels of the contour with `cv2.findNonZero`. After that you can search all the similar points like the ones that have the same x coordinate and slightly different y coordinate (in the example picture +-2) - this represents your blank space. After that you can simply draw the lines with`cv2.line()` and it will fill the blank space. Then simply search again for contours and draw bounding boxes. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img  = cv2.imread('seperated_example.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image,170,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
mask = np.zeros(gray_image.shape,np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, 255, -1)
pixelpoints = cv2.findNonZero(mask)

for i in pixelpoints:
    for j in pixelpoints:
        if int(i[:,0]) == int(j[:,0]) and int(i[:,1]) == int(j[:,1]):
            pass
        else:
            if int(i[:,0]) == int(j[:,0]) and int(j[:,1])-2 <= int(i[:,1]) <= int(j[:,1])+2:
                cv2.line(img, (int(i[:,0]), int(i[:,1])), (int(j[:,0]), int(j[:,1])), (0,0,0), 1)

cv2.imwrite('seperated_result.png', img)
cv2.imshow('img', img)

img = cv2.imread('seperated_result.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image,170,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i in contours:
    cnt = i
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)

cv2.imwrite('seperated_result2.png', img)
cv2.imshow('img2', img)
```

Input image (black text with a white line seperating it in half):

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply a median filter of at least size 3x3.